# mvc3 - set focus to control from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can I set focus to a control from a Controller when calling a View?

(I understand the typical best practice is to use jQuery to set focus to a control when the page is loaded.)

Answer (score 3):

The controller's job (one of them) is to set up a view model which gives the view enough information to render correctly. In other words, the controller and the view should only be loosely coupled.

Here's one way to do it. This is somewhat decoupled though it could be done more elegantly. You still need JavaScript to perform the client-side scripting, but the script is generated based on a value in the view model.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Foo(){

   var model = new MyViewModel();
   model.SelectedItem = "FirstName";

   return View( model );
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor( o => o.FirstName )

@if( Model.SelectedItem != default( string ) ){
    <script>$("#@(Model.SelectedItem)").focus();</script>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing you have to learn about web development is that you can have all the technologies in the world on the server, but in the end, those technologies have to generate standard (or what passes for it) Html, CSS, and JavaScript.

That means there is no special magic that can be done on the server to automatically do things on the client.  Some frameworks can automatically generate code to do this for you, but it still must be done as standard html/css/js in the end.

MVC only renders standard, plain HTML.  Webforms will do a lot of things for you, but in the end Webforms has to generate standard HTML as well.  It does this by auto generating javacript that gets included in the page that, on load sets the focus.

MVC doesn't do any of those things for you, so you would basically have to do the same thing, but you would have to write it.  It's relatively simple using some simple jquery.